# Illustrator file regains erased content when exported to PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf

I'm going out of my mind. I've erased part of a patterned shape, and when I export to PDF and look at the PDF in anything other than AI, some of the erased pattern appears again. I've tried flattening the image, I've removed a ton of layers, I've looked at the outline (ctrl-y) view and nothing fixes this problem, nor shows why it is happening.

I've included screenshots of what I'm seeing in both AI and Chrome, when opening the same exact file. Help!

[image: File viewed in AI as PDF]

[image: File viewed in Chrome as PDF]

Comment: Is it a clipping mask?

Comment: Did you look in Outlines mode in Illustrator (cmd+Y)?

Comment: Yes, I looked in outline mode and the area that is showing up on the PDF is not within the outlines.

Comment: Also, I don't think there is a clipping mask? I only erased part of the pattern from a pattern filled ellipse.

Comment: It is not possible to "erase **part** of a pattern from a pattern filled ellipses" - please *describe* exactly what you've done.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that the online version is a little shifted to one side.

I don't know what is causing that but there are ways to avoid it.

1 - You can cut the pattern a little closer but it could shift yet.

2 - you can expand the pattern:
    a - Go to Object > Expand (this will make it editable);
    b - Object > Ungroup (this will make it ready for the next step);
    c - Pathfinder > Crop (this will crop any path outside the shape).

Some images below.

[image]